# Mechanize python fails when using proxy. Browser OK with the same page

Tags: python, proxy, mechanize

I have a script that uses mechanize and proxy to connect to a web site and get some data. It logs in first
Strangely it crashes 90% of the time. Lets say I have to scrape 10 pages, 90% of the runs it will scrape < 10, and very often it will crash at log in.
Most of the errors are in the line of different timeouts and malformed data sent from the proxy (incomplete read). I get 3-4 different errors. I have set the socket timeout at 65 sec.

The same website opens OK and I can browse it with FF using the same proxy I use for python. No timeouts or errors of any sort.
I use forxy proxy in FF and in python.
Any ideas why a browser would work OK, and mechanize would fail with exactly the same proxy?